# Code for stopping a loop doesn't work

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to implement a stop to a loop in Go.
The inspiration from the code I have right now is from here:
[how to kill goroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560109/how-to-kill-goroutine#)

However, I've not been able to get my code to behave as expected. The simplified version of my code from a complex code base is this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var quit chan struct{}

var send chan int

func quitroutine() {
    for {
        select {
        case cnt := <-send:
            fmt.Println(cnt)
            if cnt == 5 {
                quit <- struct{}{}
            }
        }
    }
}

func runLoop() {
    cnt := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit!")
        default:
            fmt.Println("default")
        }
        fmt.Println("inloop")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        cnt++
        send <- cnt
    }
}

func main() {
    quit = make(chan struct{})
    send = make(chan int)
    go quitroutine()
    runLoop()
    fmt.Println("terminated")
}
```

This code crashes:

```
default
inloop
5
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.runLoop()
    /tmp/t.go:37 +0x1a6
main.main()
    /tmp/t.go:45 +0xa4

goroutine 5 [chan send]:
main.quitroutine()
    /tmp/t.go:18 +0x10e
created by main.main
    /tmp/t.go:44 +0x9f
exit status 2
```

Questions:

1. Why does it crash at all after `cnt` is 5? `quitroutine` only writes to the `quit`channel if `cnt == 5`, but doesn't terminate itself. While `runLoop`, if it receives on the `quit` channel, should just print "quit!" (**which it doesn't**), but not terminate itself.
2. Why don't I get the "quit!" output? Do I even get the `quit` channel?
3. How does this need to be implemented correctly

Comment: You aren't any `break` or `return` statements, which is what will get you out of the loops.

Comment: @Flimzy in `main()`, I am executing `go quitroutine()`. My assumption is this that in `quitroutine()`I maintain a counter, and when the counter gets to 5, it sends to `quit` in order to stop `runLoop()`, which then would terminate the complete program.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I had `return` (and `break`) in the `quit` case before, but I removed it for debuggin purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to send on the `quit` channel, the `quitroutine` blocks until something reads from it.

At the same time, the main routine, in `runloop`, is trying to send the next number on the `send` channel. This also blocks, because the routine that would be reading from it is currently blocked trying to send on the `quit` channel.

Both routines are blocked, which is a deadlock, so the program crashes.

This could be fixed by either putting one or both channel send in a `select`, or making one or both channels buffered (even a buffer length of 1 would suffice).

Answer (score 2):

Just as Adrian has said, one of your goroutines is trying to send on `quit`, while the other is trying to send on `send`. To answer your questions:

1. When `cnt == 5` the `quitroutine` begins attempting to send on `quit`. Because `quit <- struct{}{}` is not a `select` case, the goroutine will block until another tries to read from `quit`. The other goroutine is similarly stuck trying to do `send <- cnt` (when `cnt = 6`).
2. You never get the "quit!" output because that goroutine is stuck trying to do `send <-cnt`.
3. The simplest solution I see would be to adjust `runLoop()` so that the `send <- cnt` is a case in the `select`.

I'd change `runLoop()` to look like this:

```
func runLoop() {
    cnt := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit!")
        case send <- cnt: // moved stuff here
            fmt.Println("inloop")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            cnt++
        default:
            fmt.Println("default")
        }
        // stuff used to be here
    }
}
```

This gives me output (until I killed the program):

```
default
inloop
0
inloop
1
inloop
2
inloop
3
inloop
4
inloop
5
quit!
default
inloop
6
inloop
7
```

Which seems to mostly be what you were after.

I'd also like to note that the `select` block in `quitroutine()` is unnecessary because it only has one case. Cleaning that up may make it more clear that that goroutine is stuck trying to send, and never takes the input from the `send` channel.