# How to test for infinite loop/recursion with ginkgo/gomega?

Tags: go, testing, recursion, ginkgo, gomega

I have a golang function which recursively steps through a json string and replaces custom references with the json document they are referencing. I just noticed that I forgot to handle cyclic references, whose occurrence will lead to endless recursion.
Before I fix this, I'd like to write a test for this case (using ginkgo/gomega), so I can verify that my solution works and I will notice if I ever break it and run into this problem again.

But how do I do something like `if this function call does not return within <timeout>, abort it and fail the test`?

Gomega's `Eventually` has a timeout, but it doesn't abort the function if it is already running, so it will block forever in this case.

I found [this example](https://gobyexample.com/timeouts) for how to check for a timeout using `select` and channels, but from what I understood, it is not possible to terminate a goroutine from outside - so my function will continue to run in the background, eating up resources?

What is the best way to check for infinite recursion?

Comment: Normally you check for infinite recursion directly, not by trying to guess with a timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't abort a running function. The function has to support abortion, idiomatically through a [`context.Context`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context) or a channel. If you want to support timeout or abortion, you have to change / refactor your function. And the function itself has to support this, e.g. it has to monitor the `context.Context` and return early if cancellation was requested. For details and example, see [Terminating function execution if a context is cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002729/terminating-function-execution-if-a-context-is-cancelled/62002965#62002965)

See related:

[cancel a blocking operation in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240133/cancel-a-blocking-operation-in-go/28240299#28240299)

[Cancelling user specific goroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704212/cancelling-user-specific-goroutines/51704258#51704258)

Comment: So there basically is no way of doing what I want without modifying the function itself?

Comment: @DonGiovanni No. You can't even recover from it as stack overflow is an error, not a panicing state.