# Cancellation pattern in Golang

Tags: go, select, channel, worker, cancellation

Here is a quote from [50 Shades Of Go: Traps, Gotchas and Common mistakes](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/index.html#blocked_goroutines):

> You can also use a special cancellation channel to interrupt the
>   workers.

```
func First(query string, replicas ...Search) Result {  
    c := make(chan Result)
    done := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(done)
    searchReplica := func(i int) { 
        select {
        case c <- replicas[i](query):
        case <- done:
        }
    }
    for i := range replicas {
        go searchReplica(i)
    }

    return <-c
}
```

As far as understand, it means that we use channel `done` to interrupt the workers ahead of time without waiting for full execution (in our case execution of `replicas[i](query)`. Therefore, we can receive a result from the fastest worker ("First Wins Pattern") and then cancel the work in all other workers and save the resources.

On the other hand, according to the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive
>   operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send
>   statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering
>   the "select" statement.

As far as I understand, it means we cannot `interrupt the workers`, as in any case, all workers will evaluate function `replicas[i]query` and only then select `case <- done` and finish their execution.

Could you please point out at the mistake in my reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, the wording on the site is not completely clear. What this "construct" achieves is that the goroutines will not be left hanging forever, but once the searches finish, the goroutines will end properly. Nothing more is happening there.

In general, you can't interrupt any goroutine from the outside, the goroutine itself has to support some kind of termination (e.g. shutdown channel, `context.Context` etc.). See [cancel a blocking operation in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240133/cancel-a-blocking-operation-in-go/28240299#28240299).

So yes, in the example you posted, all searches will be launched, concurrently, result of the fastest one will be returned as it arrives, the rest of the goroutines will continue to run as long as their search is finished.

What happens to the rest? The rest will be discarded (`case <- done` will be chosen, as an unbuffered channel cannot hold any elements, and there will be no one else receiving more from the channel).

You can verify this in this [Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/OneR8G3EiRO).