# Golang: go func within function

Tags: go, parallel-processing

I have a function in my app that does something which is important for the rest of the app, but then must do a bunch of things that can be done in parallel in a go routine.

```
func A() {
   // some code
   go func() {
      // parallel code
   }()
}
```

Now my question is simple.  Can I trust the parallel function to continue to completion after the "parent" function (in this case function A) ends?  Or will it be cancelled if A ends before the parallel function was completed (which will most likely be the case)?
I would hope not having to use a channel to signal the end of the go routine as it kinda defeats the purpose of doing this in parallel.

Comment: It continues working

Answer (score 3):

The launched goroutine will continue to run after `A()` returns, in fact, [you can't even force a goroutine to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240133/cancel-a-blocking-operation-in-go/28240299#28240299). The only reason why goroutines are terminated if [your app ends (`main()` returns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/no-output-from-goroutine/28958240#28958240).

Also note that a goroutine does not necessarily / automatically means *parallel* execution, only *concurrent*, see [Concurrency is not parallelism](https://go.dev/blog/waza-talk).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @icza, whatever is calling `A` will not wait for the internal unnamed go-routine that is launched. If you want it to wait, you'll need a `WaitGroup`:

```
func A() {
   g sync.WorkGroup
   // some code
   
   // Increment the work-group. 
   // The anonymous routine must signal within its own context when it's finished.
   g.Add(1)
   go func() {
      defer g.Done()
      // parallel code
   }()
 
   // Wait here for the anonymous go-routine to complete.
   g.Wait()
}
```