# Alternatives to kill a goroutine/thread completely externally

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I have a grpc server which starts and stops a task. The task is run as a goroutine. I want to be able to forcefully stop the goroutine if a stop request is received regardless of what stage of execution the goroutine is in. The code looks similar to the following:

```golang
func Test() {
  test1()
  test2()
  test3()
  ... 
}
```

```golang
// in a grpc server method
go Test()
```

In this example, `Test()` takes a long time to complete (it controls some hardware which could take multiple seconds before a response is received). This `Test()` method is called from a parent as a goroutine.

I could use context or channels to stop the goroutine, however this means that I would need to check context everywhere throughout the method. In addition, there are some critical reasons for why I need the Test() method to end as abruptly as possible even if it is currently executing code that doesn't include the context checking logic.

I was reading that goroutines are meant to be stopped collaboratively. However since this option does not work for my use case, what other options do I have? Can I start a thread in go that is not a goroutine or are there any libraries that will let me achieve what I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cancel a blocking operation in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240133/cancel-a-blocking-operation-in-go) (also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6807590/11810946) for more general info).

Comment: Yeah i guess there's no easy solution. One idea I had was to use cgo and pthreads to achieve this. Are there any major disadvantages to do this?

Comment: The [FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#no_goroutine_id) has some information on why Go Routines are anonymous. You may be able to work around this (a simple approach being putting the code into a separate executable) but I'd suggest having another look at `Context` (otherwise you may end up fighting the runtime; e.g. how will garbage collection work when you have code running in a thread the runtime does not control). Note that I've never tried to do this (`Context`, or a channel, has always been good enough).

Comment: Its is factually wrong that you cannot control a goroutine ***under your control***. See https://go.dev/play/p/oQuI1XNcTs- Hence, the linked answer does not apply. This is not a duplicate of said question. I cast a reopen vote. @Brits

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I agree that there are options, however OP mentioned that using "context or channels" was something they had considered and rejected (because they want "the Test() method to end as abruptly as possible" and not rely on cooperative signalling). In that context I believe the linked answer is valid (and the other linked answer discusses options for signalling) .

Comment: @Brits Well, if you put it that way... ;)

Comment: Can you fork/exec to do the work, and kill the process? That's the only way I can think of to satisfy your requirements.